# Semaphore e Mutex em C

Tags: c, linux, thread

Eu tenho o seguinte problema:

Uma lan house com 3 pcs, vou inserir um valor X no terminal que será o número de clientes que chegam na lan house, os clientes só podem usar os pcs que estiverem desocupados, caso esteja ocupado vão para uma sala de espera, esta sala de espera suporta 15 clientes. Caso não tenha pc disponível nem espaço na sala de espera, o cliente simplesmente vai embora...

1) Sim, é um trabalho da faculdade;
2) Não, eu não quero nada resolvido de mão beijada;
3) Eu só preciso de uma ajuda para entender como resolver este problema....

Eu tenho lido bastante sobre `semaphore`, `mutex`, `threads`, mas mesmo assim o que precisa ser feito ainda é meio obscuro para mim.

Aqui é o pouquíssimo que escrevi tentando resolver este problema. Qualquer dica é muito bem vinda !

```
    #include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define ROOM_SIZE 15

sem_t queue, pc;
int room [ROOM_SIZE]; // 0 -> livre  |  != 0  -> ocupado
int pcsAvaliable = 3, roomAvaliable = ROOM_SIZE;
int computers[3] = {0, 0, 0}; // 0 -> livre  |  1 -> ocupado

struct Client{
    int id;
};

int check_computer()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        if(computers[i] == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

void insert_waitingRoom(int idClient)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< ROOM_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if(room[i] == 0)
            room[i] = idClient;
    }
}


void* Lan(void* arg)
{
    struct Client *cli = (struct Client*) arg;

    int idPC;
    int idClient = cli->id;
    if(pcsAvaliable > 0)
    {
        sem_wait(&pc);
        pcsAvaliable--;
        idPC = check_computer();
        if(idPC >= 0)
        {
            computers[idPC] = 1;
            printf("Cliente %d pegou pc %d\n", idClient, idPC);
            usleep( (   (rand() % 11) + 80) * 1000);

            computers[idPC] = 0;
            printf("Cliente %d deixou o pc %d\n", idClient, idPC);
            pcsAvaliable++;
        }
        sem_post(&pc);
        sem_post(&queue);

    }
    else
    {
        //Quando os pcs estão ocupados, o cliente fica na sala de espera.
        //Mas ele fica lá eternamente. Tem que fazer ele tentar entrar no PC e não o novo processo que vem da main.
        if(roomAvaliable >0)
        {
            sem_wait(&queue);
            roomAvaliable--;
            printf("Cliente %d foi posto na sala de espera !\n", idClient);
            insert_waitingRoom(idClient);
            while(pcsAvaliable <= 0)
            {
                //tentar acessar pc
            }


        }
    }

}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int i=0, j=1;

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        int numClients = atoi(argv[1]);
        sem_init(&pc, 0, 3);
        sem_init(&queue, 0, 15);
        pthread_t clients[numClients];

        //Create Clients
        for(i=0; i< numClients; i++)
        {
            struct Client* cli = (struct Client*) malloc(sizeof(*cli));
            cli->id = i;

            pthread_create(&clients[i], NULL, Lan, (void*)cli);
            usleep( (   (rand() % 5) + 1) * 10000);
        }
    }
    else
        printf("Por favor. Informe o número de clientes");

    sem_destroy(&pc);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente minha sugestão é criar uma estrutura de **3** espaços para os PCs (ou um `char` de 3 espaços).

```
typedef struct{
    char *nome;
    char status : 2; // 0 - livre | 1 - ocupado
    // O ": 2" especifica que em status, o valore máximo será
    // 1 e o mínimo será 0 (os valores atribuídos recebem % 2)
}PC;
```

Com essa estrutura será possível saber qual **PC** estará desocupado quando escrever o nome.

O método `Lan` tem um parâmetro, e nada mais correto que usá-lo. Nesse método, a única coisa que acontecerá será marcar o **PC** como desocupado e/não escrever o nome do **PC**.

A quantidade de *Threads* necessárias para o sistema é a quantidade de **PCs** que a *lan-house* possui.

Os clientes que extrapolarem `ROOM_SIZE+3` não precisam ser inclusos no laço, pois eles irão embora de qualquer jeito.

O `main` controlará a quantidade de pessoas que ainda estão em esperá e verificará quais **PCs** estão estão disponíveis, assim sempre que um **PC** estiver livre, já iniciará uma nova *Thread* para esse **PC**.

O código funciona normal sem o `pthread_join`, mas não há problema em usá-lo, se for usar, deixe ele logo abaixo do `pthread_create`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Meu maior problema é em usar os semáforos, não consigo fazer os clientes usarem os 3 Pcs e ficarem na fila de espera. Eles ficam revezando entre 0,1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,2 (fica eternamente entrando e saindo do 2). :O

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro, se precisar e/ou estiver interessado, posso colocar na explicação o trecho em que é feito o semáforo para controlar os PCs livres

Comment: Hey. Atualizei meu código, aparentemente (eu acho) que estou conseguindo controlar os clientes nos 3 pcs e estão revezando todos os pcs (não somente o 2 como estava antes). MAS, eu até "insiro" o  cliente na fala, porém não consigo fazer ele disputar o computador novamente. O Novo cliente (vindo do main), assume o pc e o fulano fica na fila eternamente. Poderia dar uma olhada ?